# Can updating conda libs cause problems on previous created environments?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, environments

I have some environments created as clones of our master environment, the thing that I'm wondering is that those environments have some of their libs linked to the master environment, what if I update some libs on the master? Could them be affected because the linked libraries changed?

Is there any way to update the libraries without compromising the functionality of the previous created environments?

Thank you all

Comment: environments are all independent, thus updating a library in one will not affect programs in the other libraries.

Comment: But if a library is linked to another that is updated, the environment would be affected, wouldn't it? Do you have any link reference that I could see to know how it actually works?